# In GAN, is it necessary to compile generator

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I have been working on GAN's, the thing that leave me scratching my head is that why we have to compile the generator model, even we compile the combined GAN model, then why compile generator separately.

```
def create_generator():
    generator = Sequential()

    generator.add(Dense(256, input_dim=noise_dim))
    generator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

    generator.add(Dense(512))
    generator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

    generator.add(Dense(1024))
    generator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

    generator.add(Dense(img_rows*img_cols*channels, activation='tanh'))

    generator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
    return generator

def create_descriminator():
    discriminator = Sequential()

    discriminator.add(Dense(1024, input_dim=img_rows*img_cols*channels))
    discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

    discriminator.add(Dense(512))
    discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

    discriminator.add(Dense(256))
    discriminator.add(LeakyReLU(0.2))

    discriminator.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    discriminator.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
    return discriminator

discriminator = create_descriminator()
generator = create_generator()

# Make the discriminator untrainable when we are training the generator.  This doesn't effect the discriminator by itself
discriminator.trainable = False

# Link the two models to create the GAN
gan_input = Input(shape=(noise_dim,))
fake_image = generator(gan_input)

gan_output = discriminator(fake_image)

gan = Model(gan_input, gan_output)
gan.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer)
```

As in this code one can see that generator, discriminator and gan (combined model) all three of them are compiled. According to my understanding we should be compiling only discriminator (to train discriminator) and gan (the combined model, to train the generator), because discriminator weights are frozen during GAN training as a result only generator gets trained. So why compile generator

Comment: No need to compile `G` indeed. You will just use `generator.predict()` to provide fake samples for `D` during `D` training. Make sure you have `D` weights frozen during `gan` update.

Comment: Thanks @Slowpoke for your answer, do you know any probable reason that why other people compile there generator, even though we don't need it.

Comment: @IrfanDanish If you don't compile the generator, you'll get plenty of warnings from TensorFlow. It may just be a way of getting rid of these warnings.

Answer (score 4):

During training, the `generator` and the `discriminator` have opposite goals:
the `discriminator` tries to tell fake images from real images, while the
generator tries to produce images that look real enough to trick the
discriminator.
Because the GAN is composed of two networks with different objectives, it cannot be trained like a regular neural network.
Each training iteration is divided into two phases:

- In the first phase, we train the discriminator. A batch of real
  images is sampled from the training set and is completed with an
  equal number of fake images produced by the generator. The labels are
  set to 0 for fake images and 1 for real images, and the discriminator
  is trained on this labeled batch for one step, using the binary
  cross-entropy loss. Importantly, backpropagation only optimizes the
  weights of the discriminator during this phase.
- In the second phase, we train the generator. We first use it to
  produce another batch of fake images, and once again the
  discriminator is used to tell whether the images are fake or real.
  This time we do not add real images in the batch, and all the labels
  are set to 1 (real): in other words, we want the generator to produce
  images that the discriminator will (wrongly) believe to be real!
  Crucially, the weights of the `discriminator` are `frozen` during this
  step, so backpropagation only affects the weights of the generator.

Next, we need to compile these models. The
`generator` will only be trained through the `gan model`, **so we do not need to
compile it at all**. Importantly, the `discriminator` **should not be
trained during the second phase**, so we make it `non-trainable` before
`compiling` the gan model: